# How to stack MovieClips - AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, methods, movieclip

My question is as follows:

I'm working on a game, and have a phase where the books fall
X-axis (because of the orientation of the user device to be picture) and a "small hand" than to pull it detects the book hitTestObject and the X and Y axes become the "small hand".

[image]

For the books stay stacked right, I'm using a variable on stage called HEIGHT, which the book falls into the little hand, this variable TIME is updated with the book's height, and then I position the book on the X axis with this variable .

```
    private function loop(event:Event){

        var maozinha = palco.mao;

        if(this.hitTestObject(maozinha)){
            this.y = maozinha.y;
            this.x -= palco.altura;
            palco.velocidade = 10;
            palco.gravidade = 2;
            palco.altura += 47;
            palco.pontos += 20;
            isOnHand = true;
            removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);

        } else {
            palco.velocidade += palco.gravidade;
            x += palco.velocidade;
        }

        if(x >= 940){
            removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);
            palco.life = false;
            palco.removeChild(this);
        }   
      }
   }
```

What I would like to know is if there is some method for them to automatically detect, and even when they touch the little hand or his brothers, they detect it and stop in extato point, I need to stay without calculating the height.

[image]

Below a class model for use as books ....

```
package  {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.ui.Mouse;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.*;

    public class Lverde extends Sprite {
        //VARS
        private var palco:Object;
        private var isOnHand:Boolean = false;

        public function Lverde() {
            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, inicia);
        }

        private function inicia(event:Event){
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, gameOverThis);
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, bookOnHand);
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, touchBook);
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, vitoria);
            palco = MovieClip(root);
        }

        private function gameOverThis(event:Event){
            if(palco.life == false){
                removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, gameOverThis);
                removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, bookOnHand);
                removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, touchBook);
                removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, vitoria);
                palco.removeChild(this);
            }
        }

        private function vitoria(event:Event){
            if(palco.pontos >= 200){
                palco.vitoria = true;
                palco.removeChild(this);
                removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, gameOverThis);
                removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, bookOnHand);
                removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, touchBook);
                removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, vitoria);
            }
        }

        private function bookOnHand(event:Event) {
            if(isOnHand == true){
                var maozinha = palco.mao;
                y = maozinha.y;
            }
        }

        private function touchBook(event:Event){
            if(isOnHand == false){
                for(var i:int = 0; i < palco.getChildByName("lverde").numChildren-1; i++){
                    var lverde = palco.getChildByName("lverde").getChildAt(i);

                    if(hitTestObject(lverde) && isOnHand == false){
                        palco.velocidade = 10;
                        palco.gravidade = 2;
                        palco.altura += 47;
                        palco.pontos += 20;
                        isOnHand = true;
                        trace("Tocou o livro verde");
                        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);
                        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, touchBook);
                    }
                }

                for(var i:int = 0; i < palco.getChildByName("lvermelho").numChildren-1; i++){
                    var lvermelho = palco.getChildByName("lvermelho").getChildAt(i);

                    if(hitTestObject(lvermelho) && isOnHand == false){
                        palco.velocidade = 10;
                        palco.gravidade = 2;
                        palco.altura += 68;
                        palco.pontos += 20;
                        isOnHand = true;
                        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);
                        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, touchBook);
                    }
                }

                for(var i:int = 0; i < palco.getChildByName("lmarrom").numChildren-1; i++){
                    var lmarrom = palco.getChildByName("lmarrom").getChildAt(i);

                    if(hitTestObject(lmarrom) && isOnHand == false){
                        palco.velocidade = 10;
                        palco.gravidade = 2;
                        palco.altura += 40;
                        palco.pontos += 20;
                        isOnHand = true;
                        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);
                        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, touchBook);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private function loop(event:Event){

            var maozinha = palco.mao;

            if(this.hitTestObject(maozinha)){
                this.y = maozinha.y;
                this.x -= palco.altura;
                palco.velocidade = 10;
                palco.gravidade = 2;
                palco.altura += 47;
                palco.pontos += 20;
                isOnHand = true;
                removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);

            } else {
                palco.velocidade += palco.gravidade;
                x += palco.velocidade;
            }

            if(x >= 940){
                removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);
                palco.life = false;
                palco.removeChild(this);
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

Thank U.

Comment: What do you mean by "X and Y axis become the small hand"? From the images it looks like you want to have books come from the left and move to the right and stack up on the hand. If the next book hits the stack, it would go on top. But from your explanations, I have no idea what you are talking about. Your code is also confusing because it is bloated with duplicate code and not being written in English. Could you please try to explain again what should happen?

Comment: Forgive me for bad English, I am Brazilian and I am new to AS3 ...

Well the idea is that books fall from the X axis until the little hand, and touches the little hand when your Y axis will be the helping hand (for when the user move the little hand, the book is moved together).

Also, when the book touches on another book, it has to be stacked automatically.

My question is, is there any method or function to detect the book altomaticamente as touches the little hand or in other books it stops without the need to calculate your height in the stack?

Answer (score 0):

I have rough idea of what you are trying to say (which, to be honest, is written in very poor english).
So you have books falling from the left to right, and you want the 'small hand' to catch them. If the first book hits the hand, it stops there and gets stuck to the hand. 
Now, one method to have other books stack on top of the new book, is to simply make the new book a child object of the hand, so, the new book simply becomes part of the hand. That way, the same code keeps working recursively.

Comment: The idea is the same, I'm sorry for bad English, I am Brazilian ...

I am adding children of each class to the stage ... what I would like to know is if there is some method in the books automatically detect the collision with the hand or with the other books, and no stack up automatically, without the need to be calculating the value of each book in the X axis